# python lxml.html: pull preceding text in html docstring

Tags: python, parsing, lxml, lxml.html

**I'm trying to identify a given `<table>` element based on the text that precedes it in the html document.**

My current method is to stringify each html table element and search for its text index within the file text:

```
filing_text=request.urlopen(url).read()

#some text cleanup here to make lxml's output match the .read() content
ref_text = lxml.html.tostring(filing_text).upper().\
              replace(b"&#160;",b"&NBSP;")
    tbl_count=0
    for tbl in self.filing_tree.iterfind('.//table'):
        text_ind=reftext.find(lxml.html.tostring(tbl).\
                              upper().replace(b"&#160;",b"&NBSP;"))
        start_text=lxml.html.tostring(tbl)[0:50]
        tbl_count+=1
        print ('tbl: %s; position: %s; %s'%(tbl_count,text_ind,start_text))
```

Given the starting index of the `table` element, I can then search x characters preceding for text that may identify help to identify the table's content.

**Two concerns with this approach:**

1. Since the tag density (i.e., how much of the filing text is markup versus content) varies from url to url, it's hard to standardize my search range in the preceding text.  2500 characters of html may encompass 300 characters of actual content or 2000
2. Serializing and searching once per table element seems rather inefficient.  It adds more overhead to a webscraping workflow than I'd like

**Question: Is there a better way to do this?**  Is there an lxml method that can extract text content prior to a given element?  I'm imagining something like itertext() that goes backwards from the element, recursively through the html docstring.

Comment: You could use [xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html). But can we see a little bit of your html content to better visualize and localize the text before `<table>`.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "identify" in this context. A table is defined by that text contained between the <table> </table> tags, what do you mean about the "text that precedes it"? This is just confusing to me. If I could offer anything constructive, I would say to check out Beautiful soup for parsing HTML, then perhaps all your problems go away.

Comment: @RobertB By 'identify' I mean text in the html file that describes what the following table contains.  Here is a fiddle in which the text prior to the table element is relevant to identifying it: http://jsfiddle.net/mosarani/6dchzj64/   and here is the full html document that contains this snippet: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1595262/000119312515075127/0001193125-15-075127.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use beautiful soup. Just a snippit to get you started:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> stupid_html = "<html><p> Hello </p><table> </table></html>"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(stupid_html )
>>> list_of_tables = soup.find_all("table")
>>> print( list_of_tables[0].previous )
 Hello
```

Comment: I'll check it out.  Thanks!